# Setting up AWS RDS MSSQL instance from .bak file

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to set up a MSSQL database on Amazon's RDS system. I have an instance of the database as a .bak file on S3 (and a local filesystem). I can't figure out how to populate the database with this .bak file. Is there an easy to access tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon RDS for SQL Server does not allow you to import data via a backup file.

Your choices are:

- Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard
- Import and Export Wizard
- Bulk copy feature

The Amazon RDS Users Guide has good explanations of how to do this with all three choices. [See here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ImportData.SQLServer.Import.html).

Comment: This cannot work when you have encrypted stored proceedures

Comment: How do these three options compare to large data migration offerings like AWS DMS or AWS Glue?

Answer (score 0):

AWS now supports MS SQL data restoring from a bak in S3. Attached a link with all the steps needed:

https://trailheadtechnology.com/blog/restoring-a-sql-server-backup-to-amazon-rds

Also this is the official AWS documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html